# How to find the JRE location to use the system JRE in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-20.04, openjdk-11

I'm trying to set up a java project to use openjdk-11 and all the answers I have found so far have me going in circles. I'm using ubuntu 20.04, so I used the command 'sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre'. The installation seemed to be successful but now I can't seem to figure out the file path to the installed JRE. 
I thought it would be under /user/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 somewhere. When I point eclipse to that location and try to search for a JRE however it doesn't find anything.

I have found lots of examples with info on how to install but nothing about how to track down the exact file path. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
While I was able to find the JRE location, the root problem turns out to be eclipse. I forgot I had an older version (4.6) open since that is what the project was originally using. Once I switched over to 4.18 I was able to add the java 11 JRE.

Comment: Try `which -a java` on a console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `which` will give you /usr/bin/java which won't help as it will be a symlink. You need something like

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Comment: That gets me the location of the java executable, but not the location of the JRE.

Comment: That IS the JRE

Comment: Running that command I get the result /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java . If I go go into eclipse and try to add the JRE to the installed JREs however it will fail the the error 'Target is not a JDK Root. Java executable was not found'.

Comment: That result IS a JDK. The root is  /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64. That would be what Eclipse wants to hear. Of course, there is no difference between a JRE's java and a JDK's java. Normally, in fact, you can develop in Java with just a JRE installed (i.e. no javac). Maybe that's no longer the case though

Comment: That's just it. In older versions of java the JRE was included in a subfolder of the JDK install so you could point eclipse at the root and it would pick up the JRE. In java 11 they moved the JRE somewhere else.

Comment: Actually /bin/java is still in both the JRE and JDK. They actually occur in packages openjdk-11-jdk-headless and openjdk-11-jre-headless

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer since it technically does answer the question of how to find the JRE. The solution to the overall problem turns out to be using a newer version of eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

will gives you something similar to the below:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

Comment: But that will only happen if there's just one JRE. If there are several, it won't show you the active one. update-alternatives --get-selections | grep '/java$' would, There might be a more elegant with with update-alternatives, but that will work. --config will show the active one, but of course that's not what --config is for. UPDATE: --display and --query will show you but the output might well be confusing :)